# How can I vertically align this text when I also need inline display?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a headers for the chapters in my short story using a collapsible div. I use two different fonts / styles and three layers of divs to make it look the way I want it to. Unfortunately the text is several pixels too low, and it hurts my eyes when I see it.

I know that inline display doesn't really allow for vertical align (my paddings are ignored). I tried using "inline-block" to no avail. I tried top-padding the left ">" symbol, but that makes the entire construction move downwards. I've been hammering at this for the past 2 hours, I give up :D.

[image]

Here is my HTML markup as well as the CSS.

```
<div class="ShortStoryHeaderDiv" onclick="toggleContentDiv('h1','c1');">
  <div class="ShortStoryHeaderCenterDiv">
    <div id="h1L" class="ShortStoryHeaderDivLeft">&gt;</div>
    <div class="ShortStoryHeaderText">Must... align... text</div>
    <div id="h1R" class="ShortStoryHeaderDivRight">&lt;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ShortStoryHeaderDiv
{
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #DDD;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ShortStoryHeaderCenterDiv
{
  padding-top:0.2em;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.ShortStoryHeaderDivLeft
{
  display:inline-block;
  padding-right: 3em;

  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px #555;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 17pt;
}

.ShortStoryHeaderDivRight
{
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left: 3em;

  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px #555;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 17pt;
}

.ShortStoryHeaderText
{
  display:inline;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #00F;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try and use `display:table-cell` to `vertically-align:middle`

or set a height and then set the line height to the same.

e.g. `height: 40px; line-height:40px;`

Comment: Not sure why I can't edit my post but I have done a fiddle which I think might solve the problem.  https://jsfiddle.net/0osa7h4r/

Comment: Line height pushes everything down. Thanks for the fiddle! The problem there is that it doesn't use inline anymore, and then the left & right divs fly to the extremities of the container div rather than being stuck to the central text (which is what I want).

But your vertical-align tip did wonders. In a strange way though: using table-cell didn't work, but using vertical-align:top combined with a padding-top did!

.ShortStoryHeaderText
{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  padding-top:3px;

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make it work by using this in ShortStoryHeaderText CSS class, thanks to SkelDave for reminding me about vertical align. It is awkward that the padding-top ONLY started to work once that vertical-align: top was specified. It is ignored otherwise.

```
  display:inline-block;
  padding-top:3px;
  vertical-align:top;
```